# Add filter within the perl script to remove unwanted lines from the console/output

Tags: perl, sed

Basically, I want to add the filter to the output of my perl script. This filter would chop the redundant lines matching the pattern , 'Jobs found shutdown' and would result in the clean output. Now what and where should I use grep or sed to implement this approach?? And this filter should be the part of the script which would help in getting the clean output.

I am planning to use below sed command to match the lines and remove them from the console output. But need help in implementation
have the script which has some redundant lines from the server in its output.At the end of the script , I would be running the following sed command to clear the output of the script at the console.

```
"sed -i '/No Job found./d' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `grep` is your friend in this case. Something along the lines

```
perl ... | grep -v "No Job found"
```

Will result in only lines not containing `No Job found` being printed

Comment: Now if I have my script as :#!/usr/bin/perl

use IO::File;

print "Hello World!\n";
print "Hello World!\n";
print "Hello Stack!\n";


perl ... | grep -v "Hello Stack!";      then it gives the error as "String found where operator expected at clearscript.pl line 15, near "v "Hello Stack!""
        (Do you need to predeclare v?)"

Comment: I don't understand. You said you have a perl script whose output you want to process? If so, then what I've written is a bash command, but instead of the `...` you put your actual perl file

Comment: Do you mean if my perl file is file1.pl, I should give perl file1.pl | grep -v "No Job found" at the end of file1.pl to filter the outptut of file1.pl before it gets printed at console?

Comment: No you should run this command when you run the file. That means you make your file1.pl any way you want and then run the file from console by `perl file1.pl | grep -v "No Job found"`